# Finding highest value from object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an object {1:2, 2:1}. The first one is the key and second one is the value. I want to know which one is height. From the example first one has the highest value.

How can i find it using jquery or js.

My expected output should be 
1 is highest,

if {1:1, 2:2 }
then 2 is highest.

if {1:3}
then 1 is highest.

if {2:3}
then 2 is highest.

Comment: and you've tried what?

Comment: You've said 2nd one is the value so  `{1:3}` than 3 would be the highest.

Comment: May be `Math.max.apply(null, Object.keys(YourObj))`

Comment: 1 should be highest as i has 3 value. The key value should be displayed as ans

Comment: `Object.entries(obj).reduce((a,b)=>b[1]>a[1]?b:a)[0];`

Comment: Okay than `Math.max(val1, val2)` is the best solution.

Comment: @AAShakil - really? it's an object with keys and values, Math.max doesn't know how to deal with that

Comment: @Satpal - he wants the key whose value is the highest, not the key with the highest ordinal value

Comment: What should the result be in case of equal maximum values? First, last (in natural key order), random?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following

```js
let obj = {1:2, 2:1};
let result, temp;
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k,v], i) => {
  if (i === 0 || v >= temp) {result = k; temp = v;}
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: what if all values < 0?

Comment: or you could've set temp to `-Infinity` :p

Answer (score 6):

You could reduce the entries and return the pair with the highest key/value pair and take the key only.

```js
var object = { 1: 2, 3: 3, 5: 2, 6: 7 },
    highest = Object.entries(object).reduce((a, b) => a[1] > b[1] ? a : b)[0];
    
console.log(highest);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let object  = {
  1:10,
  2:2,
  12:30,
  15:4
};

// Returns array of a given object's property names
let key = Object.keys(object)
//  Compare each value
.reduce((a, b) => object[a] > object[b] ? a : b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also find it with `for` loop by iterating each property of an object.

```js
var obj = {
    "1": 1,
    "2": 3,
    "3": 7,
    "4": 6
  },
  result, final;
for (var key in obj) {
  if (result == undefined) {
    result = obj[key];
    final = key;
  } else {
    if (obj[key] > result) {
      result = obj[key];
      final = key;
    }
  }
}
console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj = {1:2, 2:1, 3:55, 4:1, 5:60};

let highest = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(a, b){ return obj[a] > obj[b] ? a : b });

console.log(highest);
```

Comment: Could you provide some explanation as to how this solution works.

Comment: Sorry for mistake, I had returned highest value(But in question asking for key) thanks.